# How to match a string against an existing regular expression?

Tags: c#

I need to use a regular expression in my program(C#) and i cant find good Microsoft tutorial for this, could someone help me with this one:

1.This is my expression:

```
.1[4-5]iavi[0-9]{4}[A-z][A-z].bin
```

i want to send a string f to a function and i want to know if f is matching any regular expressions that i have and do something if so, like this:

```
void private Match(string f)
{

    if( f is matching to the RegularExpression1)
      add it to dictionary1..

    if( f is matching to RegularExpression2)
      add it to dictionary2

}
```

How can i write this regular expression( `.1[4-5]iavi[0-9]{4}[A-z][A-z].bin` ) inside if or something that will serve my perhaps of this function.

Thanks

Comment: Check [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(yourString, yourPattern);
```

If you have more than one pattern and you want to ensure that your string matches with all patterns, you can store them into an array then use `Regex.IsMatch` with `Enumerable.All` method like this:

```
 var patterns = new[] {"pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3"};

 return patterns.All(pattern => Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
```

Comment: and how i write my pattern? just with"" ?
because i saw people using the @ also...
could you be more specific with your answer?

Comment: @RonKah if you have any special character in your pattern for example `"\b"` you need to escape backslah with `"\\b"`, or you can use `@"\b"` and make it verbatim string. in your current pattern there is no special character so you can write it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET documentation for Regular Expressions is available on the MSDN pages below:

[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).